# Textinput: toggle focus on first input if array is empty or has content

Tags: javascript, react-native, textinput

I can't quite find the answer to this situation.

Functional component.

Screen has a text input field for names which, onSubmit, adds the name to an array. Screen then shows the names in the array in list form.

What I want is to set the TextInput to:

```
 autoFocus={true}
```

but only if the array is empty.

If the array has one or more items:

```
 autoFocus{false}
```

I tried

```
 autoFocus{arrayLength}
```

with:

```
 const [arrayLength, setArrayLength] = useState(false)
```

then with useEffect:

```
 AsyncStorage.getItem("savedNames").then((value) => {
  const myList = JSON.parse(value);
  if (myList === null || myList.length === 0) {
    setSavedNames([]);
    setFocusState(true);
    console.log("hey");
  } else {
    console.log("ho");
    setSavedNames(myList);
    setFocusState(false);
  }
});
```

}, [savedNames, focusState]);

and in the TextInput:

```
 <TextInput
          autoFocus={focusState}
          onSubmitEditing={() => doAllSortsOfStuff()}
        />
```

Which doesn't work. The console shows the correct response, just that focus does not change based on state.

With class components, it seems that ref's are required to make this work, for some strange reason.

Is there a simple solution to this for functional components?

Comment: Which part doesn't work? I'm guessing it isn't focusing when it should (`focusState=true`). If so, it's because you change the `autoFocus` prop long after the input component has mounted, and `autoFocus` only takes effect on component mount.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. But with a class component you can wrangle the focus with refs. Was wondering how that would be done with a functional component, or if there was a different method, besides refs, to make it happen. Seems like a common situation to have so there must be a simple solution.

Comment: Well, you could render the input component conditionally, so that it mounts AFTER you have fetched the list (`{didFetchList && <Input autoFocus={focusState} />}`). However, I would suggest you get used to refs. They're quite useful. Check out `useImperativeHandle` for functional component refs. Although, you probably don't ever need to put a ref on a functional component. `TextInput` is a class component internally.